# Transitive form of to qualify

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether the following sentence is correct?

> These guys qualified to lead the groups into the mountain.

I feel it should be "This guys **are** qualified ...".

Answer (score 1):

"Are" could have been omitted, as you note, but also one of the meanings of 'qualify' (verb) is "become officially recognized as a practitioner of a particular profession or activity, typically by undertaking a course and passing examinations: "The training necessary to qualify as a group leader". These guys qualified. British English speakers might say "the guys have qualified".